# como puedo solucionarlo list index out of range

Tags: mysql, python, sql, django

Tengo un query y ese query solo me arroja un registro y cuando lo optengo le pido que me arroje el el valor que este en la posicion [0]

```
for a in datos_estados:
    tabla_datos = [a["estado"], a["seccion"], 'Teorico']
    for vuelta in range(mes_inicio, 13):
        query = '''
                    SELECT NVL(TRIM(TO_CHAR(SUM(TOTAL),'999,999,999,999,999.00')),0) "teorico"
                    FROM CL_RP_COBRANZA_TNR_TEORICO
                    WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,'MM/RRRR')='{0}/{1}' AND
                          ESTADO='{2}' AND 
                          SECCION='{3}'
                    GROUP BY  ESTADO, 
                          SECCION
                    ORDER BY ESTADO, SECCION'''.format(vuelta, ano_inicio,a["estado"],a["seccion"])
        #print query
        datos_teorico = consulta_asociativa(query, conexion['cursor'])[0]
        tabla_datos.append(datos_teorico["teorico"])
        tabla_datos.append(" ")
```

---

En la consulta no existe ningun registro en la BD, por esa razon es por la que no encuentre la posicion [0], pero como puedo evitar que no arroje error?

Comment: ¿Dónde se produce el error?¿En  la línea `consulta_asociativa(query, conexion['cursor'])[0]`? La traza completa del error siempre es de ayuda. el error es causado por intentar indizar sobre una lista que no tiene ese índice, por ejemplo `>>> l = []`: `>>> l[0]`, la solución depende de la situación, desde comprobar si la lista está vacía con `if lista: ...,`manejo del `IndexError`, evitar que se produzca la situación directamente modificando la lógica adecuadamente si es posible, etc.

Comment: Perfecto ya encontre el error. pero me gustaria por favor, me pueda ayudar

Comment: SELECT NVL(TRIM(TO_CHAR(SUM(TOTAL),'999,999,999,999,999.00')),0) "teorico"
                    FROM CL_RP_COBRANZA_TNR_TEORICO
                    WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,'MM/RRRR')='{0}/{1}' AND
                          ESTADO='{2}' AND 
                          SECCION='{3}'
                    GROUP BY  ESTADO, 
                          SECCION
                    ORDER BY ESTADO, SECCION'''.format(vuelta, ano_inicio,a["estado"],a["seccion"])

Comment: en la consulta no existe ningun registro en la BD, por esa razon es por la que no encuentre la posicion [0], pero como puedo evitar que no arroje error?

Comment: No sé de qué tipo será lo que retorna `consulta_asociativa`, pero si es algo similar a una lista posiblemente podrás aplicarle la función `len()` para saber si tiene elementos, antes de intentar acceder al primero "a ciegas".

Comment: Debes de colocar un Try Except. De esta manera evitas que el programa colapse repentinamente por el error. Además, puedes hacer un if para comparar si el len del arreglo es 0, si es cero, no lees el arreglo y evitas que se produzca el error.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy suponiendo que la función consulta_asosiada te devuelve un queryset

```
    datos_teorico = consulta_asociativa(query, conexion['cursor'])
    if datos_teoricos.exists():
        tabla_datos.append(datos_teorico[0]["teorico"])
        tabla_datos.append(" ")
```